# Icon doesn't Appair just after logout and login steps on Android React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, icons

the issue is in the icon type = **evilicon** the error is when i load my page after Login and get a navigate to the screen the icon not appair just for Android !! for IOS it's working !

i try it with Expo Mobile for IOS work Correctly and not for Android directly but when i logout and login again the Icon appair !!!

```
 <Icon
          iconStyle={styles.icon}
          name="pencil"
          type="evilicon"
          size="230" 
          color="#04871a"
        />
```

How to get the Icon appair for the first time for Android without logout and login everytime ?

what is the problem ?

thanks Guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something is wrong with your import or sdk version. Not sure from your given code. More details is requried.

For now, import and try [this icon](https://icons.expo.fyi/EvilIcons/pencil). I think this will give the exact same icon you need.